# Find $\lim_{k\to 2}\frac{2^{2^k}-2^{k^2}}{2^k-k^2}$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Find $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to 2}\frac{2^{2^k}-2^{k^2}}{2^k-k^2}$

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
A&=\lim_{k\to 2}\frac{2^{2^k}-2^{k^2}}{2^k-k^2}\\
\ln A&=\lim_{k\to 2}\ln\frac{2^{2^k}-2^{k^2}}{2^k-k^2}\\
&=\lim_{k\to 2}(\ln(2^{2^k}-2^{k^2})-\ln(2^k-k^2))
\end{align*}
I stuck at $\ln(0)$.

Comment: Maybe L'Hospital rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{k\to2}\dfrac{2^{2^k}-2^{k^2}}{2^k-k^2}=\lim_{k\to2}2^{k^2}\cdot\lim_{k\to2}\dfrac{2^{2^k-k^2}-1}{2^{k}-k^2}$$

Now use $2^{k}-k^2=y$ as $2=e^{\ln2},$

$$\implies\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{2^y-1}y=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{e^{y\ln2}-1}y=\ln2$$

Answer (score 2):

Applying L'Hopital's rule you get
$$
\lim_{x\to 2}\dfrac{2^{x+2^x} \log ^2 2-2^{x^2+1} x \log (2)}{2^x \log 2-2 x} = 16 \log 2.
$$